# Zend 2 Skeleton. Customize Application module or create own module?

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-application

I downloaded the [Zend 2 Skeleton Application](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/user-guide/skeleton-application.html) which comes with the module "Application". This module is the central point of the "Framework".
Now I want to add some routes/pages like "terms", "contact" etc. That brings me to the essential question:

Is it best practise to customize the "Application" module or am I supposed to create my own module? Especially if I want to add some static pages? If I'm gonna customize the Application module I can't update the Framework via composer anymore, I guess.

Thanks for everyone's help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends. If you wanna edit this "static pages" via wysiwyg make separate module for pages (CMS ?)
If you will have pure static pages just add new controllers to Application.

Current trend is to make API in backend and use some frontend framework for front (so front-end will be responsible for load proper views)